# What is the point of making a method generic when it has only one generic type anyway?

Tags: java, generics, generic-method

If a method is defined as:

```
<T> List<T> transform(List<T> list)
```

What does the first T add? As it is essentially the same as:

```
List<T> transform(List<T> list)
```

Answer (score 4):

`<T>` is the definition. You need to define generic type parameters before you use them, just like you must define variables before you use them.

---

Remember, `T` is just a naming convention. That identifier can be anything. It could be `<F>` or `<Foo>`.

Suppose they implemented it how you suggest, and the compiler just *infers* any missing type to be a generic type parameter. Suppose I have a custom class `Foo` which I forgot to import.

```
List<Foo> transform(List<Foo> list)
```

The compiler would say "*Ok, I don't know what Foo is, so let's just assume it's a generic parameter*". Your method then compiles just fine, when you would much prefer that the compiler had caught that mistake.

Or maybe you think `T` should be a special case. You would then be taking something that's currently just a convention and making that a special part of the language. You'd have to deal with the possibility of someone creating a real class called `T`.

So explicit declarations have their uses, even if they may seem verbose sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is the scope of `T`. It can be defined on the class level or for each individual method.

```
List<T> transform(List<T> list)
```

This one returns and accepts `List<T>` where `T` is the same for all methods.

```
<T> List<T> transform(List<T> list)
```

This method has its own `T` unrelated to the generic type of its class (if any).

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> <T> List<T> transform(List<T> list)
> ```
>
> As it is essentially the same as:
>
> ```
> List<T> transform(List<T> list)
> ```

It's not.

In the second case, `T` has to have been defined on the containing class:

```
class GenericClass<T> {
  List<T> transform(List<T> list) { ... }
}
```

and you can then only pass in/get back a list of the same element type as the class:

```
GenericClass<String> genericClass = new GenericClass<>();
List<String> stringList = genericClass.transform(Arrays.asList(""));  // OK.
List<Integer> intList = genericClass.transform(Arrays.asList(0));  // Error!
```

However, with the first form, the `T` isn't defined on the class, so it can be different on each invocation:

```
class NonGenericClass {
  <T> List<T> transform(List<T> list) { ... }
}

NonGenericClass nonGenericClass = new NonGenericClass();
List<String> stringList = nonGenericClass.transform(Arrays.asList(""));  // OK.
List<Integer> intList = nonGenericClass.transform(Arrays.asList(0));  // OK.
```

Comment: The second case may refer to the class or interface `T` instead of the type parameter `T`.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the same at all.

The `<T>` declares the variable, the rest is the use of the variable. This straight up fails to compile:

```
public class Example {
    public List<T> transform(List<T> foo) {}
}
```

try it.

In case this is what you have:

```
public class Example<T> {
    public <T> List<T> transform(List<T> foo) {}
}
```

Then you have 2 unrelated type variables, both unfortunately named `T`, which is extremely confusing; I strongly suggest you don't do that (the class has defined a  and then the method defines its own T, ensuring that all uses of T in that method declaration are assumed to be the  defined on the method; the  defined by the class is no longer accessible; it has been 'shadowed'. It is in that sense equivalent to this:

```
public class Example {
    int x;

    public void foo(int x) { }
}
```

The `int x` of foo is **utterly unrelated** to the `int x;` field, but because they have the same name, you have made it impossible to refer to the field named `x`. At least for this there's an escape (`this.x` still refers to the field) - no such luxury with generics, so, do not shadow variables like this.

It is somewhat unlikely you want a type var on the method at all if you have this code; but if you really do, don't use T, but use anything else:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    public <Y> List<Y> transform(List<Y> foo) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As was already said, the following are essentially identical.

```
<T> List<T> transform(List<T> list)

List<T> transform(List<T> list)
```

But the former also allows one to further constrain T.  For example you can do

```
<T extends Foo> List<T> transform(List<T> list) {
...   
}
```

You can only pass a `List<T>` if T subclasses Foo.